# Method was removed after version 58.0: getSalesforceBaseUrl

Tags: apex, winter24

I'm trying to call `system.debug(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl());`
and receive the following message:

```
Method was removed after version 58.0: getSalesforceBaseUrl
```

I've checked the documentation for v58.0 and this method is still there:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_url.htm#apex_System_URL_getSalesforceBaseUrl

what is the alternative for that method and where can I get the info about the reasons for removal of that method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Url.getSalesforceBaseURL() will no longer be usable in Apex code with a version of 59.0 or above starting in Winter '24.

[Url.getOrgDomainURL()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.246.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_url.htm#apex_System_Url_getOrgDomainUrl) is the suggested replacement that will always return a consistent value for a given org. And, [getCurrentRequestURL()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.246.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_url.htm#apex_System_URL_getCurrentRequestUrl)  can be used in other cases where getSalesforceBaseURL() would return a value based on the current request's hostname.

The concerned Salesforce Product Development team is working on having this documented as part of internal investigation `#W-12643965`

---

Update: From [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_url.htm#apex_System_URL_getSalesforceBaseUrl):

> getSalesforceBaseUrl()
>
> In API version 59.0 and later, this method is deprecated and versioned
> out. Use getOrgDomainUrl() to get the canonical URL for your org or
> use getCurrentRequestUrl() to get the URL of an entire request on a
> Salesforce instance. Returns the URL of the current connection to the
> Salesforce org.
>
> Signature
>
> public static System.URL getSalesforceBaseUrl()